# Is there a Kabbalistic source for not walking with one's hands behind one's back?

Tags: minhag, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, hands-fingers

I've heard from people that it says in Kabbalah that one shouldn't walk with one's hands behind one's back. Does anyone know the source?

Comment: Is it not simply because it may upset your balance? Or if you trip, your hands won't be available to break your fall?

Comment: @AviD - that doesn't sound very kabbalistic to me!

Comment: Where is @mekubal when we need him...?

Comment: Btw, there is a kabalistic concept not to ever 'cross' your limbs.  Front or back, legs or arms. Has to do with preventing brachot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4591&st=%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98%D7%A9&pgnum=72&hilite=62bf336b-2b1f-467b-b6e3-d92658173580) - 3rd par.) quoting the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe )([here - 2nd col., 2nd par.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=19806#p=p51)), tells a story of the Alter Rebbe (the Baal Hatanya) in which he (the Previous Rebbe) mentions that the Alter Rebbe didn't hold his hands behind his back al pi kabbalah. This wasn't even referring to folding one's hands, let alone walking.
The Alter Rebbe was warming his hands by the stove in the back of the room while looking and listening to a conversation in the front. Nevertheless, the Rebbe says, he was careful not to put his hands behind his back, but at his sides. Since the Alter Rebbe lived 1745 - 1812, this story took place before the Ben Ish Chai was born (1833).

An anonymous comment [here](http://theantitzemach.blogspot.com/2008/12/pic-of-day.html?showComment=1229658240000#c5845681577976120179) says that in another one of the Lubavitcher Rebbe's seforim (perhaps [here](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=HRE-TM38), can't find an online copy) there is a footnote by the place where the Rebbe mentions that not putting one's hands behind one's back is kabalistic: "
(ראה שער רוה"ק דרוש א' הב' (קרוב לסופו". Despite spending some time looking through [that sefer](http://hebrewbooks.org/35324), I was unable to find the source, although I didn't fully understand the above footnote, so perhaps I was looking in all the wrong places.

Significantly, this predates the Ben Ish Chai, is an example of a prominent personality being careful about this, and would also seem to debunk R. Aviner's assertion that it is superstitious.

Comment: Perhaps that's it. But what on earth does קשרי הזרועות mean?

Comment: Hmm. The rest of that piece still confuses me, though.

Comment: the ben ish hai was mentioned since it is a easier access book than rabenu ari writings, which people don't have at home so easily as the ben ish hai, in any case this is not his hidush he brings sources to ari.

Comment: @Avraham I was merely pointing out that the Ben Ish Chai wasn't the original source, and that this was a good indication of such.

Comment: @HodofHod: a better proof that the Ben Ish Chai wasn't the original source might be the ben ish chai himself, who says he's quoting the shaar ruach hakodesh of the arizal - see Pinchas Year 2, paragraph 18: http://www.shechem.org/torah/benishhi/sheni/pages/bamidbar/143.gif - taken from http://www.shechem.org/torah/benishhi/sheni/pinchas.html

Comment: @Menachem True, but this is the oldest definite source I've seen. (I tried to follow that Shaar Ruach Hakodesh source but couldn't find anything definite). In addition it is the earliest story I know of in which a Torah personality is machmir in this. That being said, you're right, the Ben Ish Chai himself does say he's not the original source.

Comment: @HodofHod For the same price that the primary source quoted (Ben Ish Chai) is later than the Ba'al HaTanya, the primary source you quoted (Lubavitcher Rebbe) is not earlier than the Ben Ish Chai.  So mima nafshach...

Comment: @YEZ The point was to give an _example_ of this idea prior to the Ben Ish Chai, as well as a prominent Torah personality being careful about it. Unless you mean to say that the (Previous) Lubavitcher Rebbe isn't reliable enough. So yes, if that's your assumption, then the story is not a reliable example of this idea predating the Ben Ish Chai. (Imagine someone using the Zohar to say that a concept preceded, say, the Ramban. If you accept the Zohar as being from the Rashbi, the answer stands. Otherwise not.) So just like everything in Judaism, it depends on whether you rely on the transmission.

Comment: @HodofHod So is the Ben Ish Chai not reliable then?  Otherwise, what have you gained?  The Arizal predates any of those in your chain of transmission.  If his chain is reliable, then you're not really adding anything.  (Your point about an example I am not taking issue with.  Just your statement of finding the "oldest definite source" - you didn't find anything older and more definite than previously established)

Comment: @YEZ I haven't seen a definite source in the Arizal (the Ben Ish Chai doesn't cite one AFAICT), so while I trust the Ben Ish Chai of course, I brought an older _definite_ (i.e., "clearly defined") transmission "chain link." Does it make the idea more _reliable_? No, I'd agree with you that it probably does not. If you want to, feel free to remove that part; I concede that it doesn't add much.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=2188&txtSearch=arizal
It is brought down in Ben Ish Hai, but other Aharonim discuss it at length.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard in the name of the Bostoner Rebbe zt'l that that posture indicates arrogance.

Comment: I'd say it's more Hassidic than Kabbalistic per se, as far as I know.

Comment: I remember seeing this (that kabbalistically, one should not put his hands behind his back) in a sefer many years ago, but I can no longer remember where. It wasn't just a "mussar" thing.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipID=2188) records the concept in the name of Ben Ish Chai. He's probably not the earliest source, though.

Comment: Significantly, that article classifies the [anti-]practice as "well-documented" and possessing a "clear basis in sources", as opposed to "folklore" or "superstition".

Answer (score 3):

I heard in the name of maran ahida, after I asked to a cabalistic rav he confirmed and explaned me why.

I believe you may ask any sepharadic cabalist rabbi.

see also ben ish hai second year parashat pinehas, last saif. I believe he brings others sources there too

Comment: nu, what did he say?

Answer (score 2):

R. Aviner says that such an idea is pure superstition. (in one of his text teshuvot which I get in emails, so I can't link to it)

Comment: [This one?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner)

Comment: Yes.  Also, his name is pronounce 'avi-nair' not 'avinr'  It's a mistake I used to make.

Comment: @avi: can you quote the relevant parts here?

Comment: Perhaps for Ashkenazim, but Sephardim the Ben Ish Hai brings it down.