# What is the proper way to hold one's hands while praying?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hands-fingers

Similar to [Not interlacing fingers in prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26931/1713)

What is the proper way that one should hold his hands while praying, if there is such a way?  What is the level of obligation to hold one's hands in that way? Is it required at all?

Comment: One holding the siddur, one turning pages? :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, That's the way I do it :)

Comment: Me too, the vast majority of the time.  Sure, there *are* prayers I can (and sometimes do) do from memory, but usually I'm holding a siddur anyway.  (And you said "prayer", which I scoped more narrowly than, say, any b'racha.  If the distinction matters you might want to clarify.)

Answer (score 1):

The Rama 91:6 brings the words of the Tur(which comes from shabbas 10 Rav Ashi brings that Rav Kahana did this) that in times of fury one should clasp his hands like a servant in fear,and in times of peace one should dress in nice cloths for prayer.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.torah.org/learning/tefilah/handpositions.html this is something down your road.However,  I follow RaMbaM who says like the gamoroh brought down on that site, that one should put his right on top of his left.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Gutman Locks in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVjP9mzOEE4) shows how you should hold your hands during prayer. He says that one should put his left fist on the left side of his chest, and then put the right hand over the left.

Here's a snapshot from the video showing him doing it:

[image]